# How to safely read properties of a WebScriptObject?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview, webkit

When communicating between JavaScript in a `WebView` instance and a `WebViewDelegate`, JavaScript types and Objective-C types are converted back and forth. For instance, when calling an Objective-C function from JavaScript, a string becomes an `NSString`, a number becomes an `NSNumber`, and an Object becomes a `WebScriptObject`.

The others are pretty simple to deal with, but `WebScriptObject` seems weird.

When passing a dictionary like `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}`, most of the code I see extracts the properties using `valueForKey`, such as in `[[arg valueForKey:@"foo"] intValue] == 1`

But what about if you're not sure if the property exists? What if the keys are optional? `[arg valueForKey:@"baz"]` throws an exception.

One thing I can do is something like

```
@try {
  foo = [[arg valueForKey:@"baz"] intValue];
}
@catch (NSException* e) {
  foo = 0;
}
```

but I've heard that exceptions in Objective-C are unsafe and should not be used for flow control.

The only other way I can think of is some variation of the method used here: http://edotprintstacktrace.blogspot.com/2011/10/sample-webscriptobject-javascript.html

In other words: 1. use `evaluateWebScript` to define a JavaScript function that implements `Object.keys` 2. call that function on your `WebScriptObject` 3. iterate through the returned array of keys, and only call `valueForKey` if we find a match.

This seems incredibly inefficient, to me. There must be a better way... is there?

Answer (score 4):

Since OS X 10.9 and iOS 7 there is a ways more easy way to do this. Apple introduced a class named `JSValue` wich can be used to bridge JavaScript objects to regular ObjC objects:

```
// WebScriptObject *options; obtained from a callback in ObjC
id objCObject = [[options JSValue] toObject];

if ([objCObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (id object in objCObject) {
        NSLog(@"object: %@", object);
    }
}
else if ([objCObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    for (id<NSCopying> key in [objCObj allKeys]) {
       NSLog(@"object for key %@: %@", key, [objCObject objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I found something that works - the trick is that you can convert WebScriptObject to JSObjectRef with -JSObject, and there's a whole bunch of C methods that work on JSObjectRefs, though the docs are a bit lacking so it's hard to figure out what to do exactly.

Here's how you can check if a property exists:

```
id getProperty(WebScriptObject *obj, NSString *prop) {
    JSStringRef jsProp = JSStringCreateWithCFString((__bridge CFStringRef) prop);

    if (JSObjectHasProperty(self.frame.globalContext, [obj JSObject], jsProp)) {
       return [options valueForKey:prop];
    } else {
       return nil;
    }

    JSStringRelease(jsString);
}
```

If you want to list all properties (whose keys aren't known in advance), you'll need to use a few more functions:

```
JSPropertyNameArrayRef properties =
    JSObjectCopyPropertyNames(self.frame.context, [obj JSObject]);

size_t count = JSPropertyNameArrayGetCount(properties);

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    JSStringRef property = JSPropertyNameArrayGetNameAtIndex(properties, i);
    // ... etc. as above
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `properties` array from? And what is `options`?

Comment: And what is this a subclass of

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear indeed... In this case, `options` is the `WebScriptObject` that I want to extract things from. `properties` is some kind of array of fields that you're interested in, if you know in advance what keys you want to check in the dictionary.

If you want to read arbitrary objects whose keys you don't know in advance, you can use `JSObjectCopyPropertyNames` to get the list of keys from the `JSObject` and then `JSPropertyNameArrayGetCount` and `JSPropertyNameArrayGetNameAtIndex` to process that array.

Comment: Great, THANKS. This ist good information. I discovered an easier way. You can do this: `[[options JSValue] toObject]`, thats it, you'll end up with a `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` Unfortunately I didn't find a solution the other way around, yet.

Comment: Would you also update your answer? That would be great. Please don't hide solutions in the comments :D

Comment: Great, now this is a **REALLY** helpful answer ;) Did you note my 10.9+/7.0+ solution?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really need that code anymore, so I won't bother changing this.